# I don't understand the stage output voltage swing of a common source amplifier

Tags: voltage

In a common source stage amplifier, peak of swing is VDD-(VGS-VTH1).

I don't know why that voltage level is like that.

Could anyone give me some intuitive explanation?

[image: CS Stage amplifier]

Comment: The positive peak of the output voltage swing will be VDD so, maybe you have misinterpreted something? Either way, you should provide a link to the source that states the formula you wrote.

Comment: You should also provide a source of the image you've used.

Comment: Cheon SeockBeom - Hi, (a) Since you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as this site's rules differ from typical forums. (b) For completeness and as already commented, it is a [site rule](/help/referencing) that any material which you copy or adapt and post onto Stack Exchange, is correctly referenced. For online sources, add the webpage / PDF / video name and its link. For offline sources (e.g. printed books) then a normal citation should be given. See the site rule for details. Please [edit] your question to add the missing details. TY